# Trying to understand this property: $\int\limits_a^b f(x) dx = \frac{1}{k}\int\limits_{ka}^{kb}f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus

I know that this property is elementary, but it's not clear to me yet how to interpret it:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \frac{1}{k}\int_{ka}^{kb}f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)dx$$

As I understand this, if for a function $f$ we want the integral on the interval $[ka, kb]$ to be equal to that on $[a,b]$, we will need to undo its stretching: $f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$ does just that.

What I'm not getting is the reciprocal of $k$ before the integral.

In a similar way I have been undertanding the property of linearity: $f(x-c)$ undoes the shifting of the closed interval $[a+c,b+c]$, which in turn make the integral equal to that of the same function $f$ but on $[a,b]$.

Apostol's Calculus I constructs the proofs of these two properties from the equivalent properties for step functions. Although I'm able to follow the proofs in both cases, that of expansion/contraction of the interval of integration remains unnatural to me.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $u=kx$. Then $x=\frac{u}{k}$. $dx=\frac{1}{k}du$. When $x=a$ then $u=ka$ and when $x=b$ then $u=kb$. So this is a result of integration by substitution. ($u$ was rewritten by $x$ afterwords.)

**EDITED**

Let's consider a function being constant on an interval and zero elsewhere. Stretching it out by a factor of $k$ without changing the height will increase the area under the curve (the area of the rectangle) by the same factor. Dividing the new area by $k$ will undo the unwanted increasing. The integral of a function can be approximated by summing up certain rectangles...

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: I think OP knows the proof but wants an intuitive explanation for the factor of $1/k$.